Induction over recurrence relation $c(n,k) = (n-1)c(n-1,k)+c(n-1,k-1)$
I am stuck on a proof. I know that $b(n,0) = c(n,0)$ for all $n \geq 1$, and that $b(0,0) = c(0,0)$. Furthermore, I know that
\begin{align*} b(n,k) &= c(n,k)\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
if $n < k$. We also know that the recurrence relation $$c(n,k) = (n-1)c(n-1,k)+c(n-1,k-1)$$ hold for both $b(n,k)$ and $c(n,k)$ with $n,k \geq 1$. I want to show that it follows that $b(n,k) = c(n,k)$ for $k,n \geq 1$. I think I need to do some kind of double-induction over both $n,k$ since I don't see a way to do it for fixed $n$ and just over $k$, the reason being the term $b(n-1,k)$ in the recurrence relation not being amenable to a single induction over $k$.
Am I correct that I need start by doing an induction over $n$. The base case $b(0,k) = c(0,k)$ hold for all $k$ since we know it holds if $n < k$ and if $k = 0$ they also agree.
In the inductive step, we assume that it holds for some $m \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and want to show it holds for $m+1$, with respect to the first argument. Then we proceed with $k$. For the base case, we have that $b(m,0) = c(n,0)$. We assume it holds for $\ell \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and want to show it holds for $\ell+1$.
We then have
\begin{align*}
b(m+1,\ell+1) &= (m)b(m,\ell+1) + b(m,\ell)\\
&= (m)c(m,\ell+1)+c(m,\ell)\\
&= c(m+1,\ell+1) 
\end{align*}
where we used induction in the second equality.
Is this a valid form of induction?

Why not just start with "$b(n,0j=c(n,0)$ for all $n\geq0?$" And what is $b?$

What $b(n,k)$ is has no relevance for what I am interested in proving here, apart from where I have defined it on particular $(n,k)$, AFAICT.
